# react-native-webview high vulnerability UXSS

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I started a new ReactNative app and tried to use webview for playing Youtube Video
It was ok the last time i used it but this time when i install the package i get a high vulnerability message :
" High   Universal XSS in Android WebView"
More info : https://npmjs.com/advisories/1560

My questions :

- can we use it despite this message or it will be rejected by the Play Store ?
- otherwise do you know how to fix it ?
  Or
- do you know another way to do it (without using react-native-youtube)

Answer (score 1):

It is good that you are security aware!

**Can we use it?**

I don't think Google will reject your app. In other words, we launched a few apps using react-native-webview and did not experience any problem when launching on Google Play.

This vulnerability affects React Native apps which use a react-native-webview **that allows navigation to arbitrary URLs**. I don't think you use the webview that way.

So, yes, I think you can use it.

**How to fix it?**

As found in the advisory https://npmjs.com/advisories/1560:

> Ensure users update their Android WebView system component via the
> Google Play Store to 83.0.4103.106 or higher to avoid this UXSS.
> 'react-native-webview' is working on a mitigation but it could take
> some time.

So you have to be patient and wait for a fix. The way you use it is save.